Upload File with FlaskForm Render_form
I can succesfully Upload a file using:
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">.

However I can not combine this method with logging in my user.
I want to login my user using the render_form method:
{{ render_form(form, novalidate=True)}}

However, I can't find a way to support uploading a file with this method.

{{ wtf.quick_form(form,enctype="multipart/form-data") }}

    {% macro render_form(form, action) %}
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <div id="Product" class="variant-block" style="display: block;">
            {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
            {% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form,enctype="multipart/form-data")  }}
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}


More info. here: https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/macros/
